# Passing multiple arguments in multiprocessing in Python

Tags: python, multiprocessing

This may be trivial, but for me takes long time to solve in Python.
I tried to implement multiprocessing and I used pool.
I need to pass multiple arguments.
Then I implement like

```
def doWork(worker_args):
bbox_list, conf_list, all_rects, w, h, pix_per_w, n = worker_args

sys.stdout.write("w: %d%%   \n" % n )
sys.stdout.flush()

for k in range(h * w):
    conf = conf_list[n][k,1].flatten()[0]
    if conf > 0.75:
       y = int(k / w)
       x = int(k % w)
       bbox = bbox_list[n][k]
       abs_cx = pix_per_w/2 + pix_per_w*x + int(bbox[0,0,0])
       abs_cy = pix_per_h/2 + pix_per_h*y+int(bbox[1,0,0])
       w = bbox[2,0,0]
       h = bbox[3,0,0]
       all_rects[y][x].append(Rect(abs_cx,abs_cy,w,h,conf))
```

Then from main, I sent as

```
         all_rects = [[[] for x in range(net_config["grid_width"])] for y in range(net_config["grid_height"])]
         pool = multiprocessing.Pool(len(bbox_list))
         worker_args = [(bbox_list, conf_list, all_rects, net_config["grid_width"], net_config["grid_height"], pix_per_w, range(len(bbox_list)))]
         pool.map(doWork, worker_args)
```

Then error in printing `n in doWork` function is

```
TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not list
```

If I implement like

```
def doWork(n): and 
in main
pool.map(doWork, range(len(bbox_list)))
```

It works. Send data from 0 to 5.

Then I implement like

```
def doWork(worker_args): and 
in main
worker_args = [(bbox_list, conf_list, all_rects, net_config["grid_width"], net_config["grid_height"], pix_per_w)]
pool.map(doWork, worker_args)
```

It works also.
But if I combine two as in the first example, then I got error at n.
How to send n in single digit, not in list?
Thanks

Comment: Could the answers in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5442910/) help? E.g., [one answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21292849/1016514) mentions a small library, *parmap* that extends the Python map to handle multiple arguments.

Comment: firstly, I don't think `map` from `multiprocessing` works as you're expecting.  it will call you `doWork` function with each element of the `worker_args`.  If you want to pass multiple parameters they need to be `zip`ped up, or an alternative could be to pass an `initializer` to the pool and pass in the shared state there.

Comment: @SamMason, thanks. My another issue is the way I implement, it has memory issue. I am expecting send by reference. Actually it is not. How to implement send by reference? (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/986006/how-do-i-pass-a-variable-by-reference) this discussion says about byvalue or byreference.

Comment: This article (http://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#how-do-i-write-a-function-with-output-parameters-call-by-reference) passed by assignment. Since assignment just creates references to objects, there’s no alias between an argument name in the caller and callee, why I have memory issue? All memories are used and program hanged after running sometime.

Comment: I'd post a separate question about variable references.  Judging from your other questions you seem trying to learn a lot all at once, try slowing down and learning each concept in greater detail before trying to combine them with other new ideas